# Python remove all apostrophes from a string

Tags: python

I wanted to remove all occurrences of single and double apostrophes in lots of  strings.

I tried this-

```
mystring = "this string shouldn't have any apostrophe - \' or \" at all"
print(mystring)
mystring.replace("'","")
mystring.replace("\"","")
print(mystring)
```

It doesn't work though! Am I missing something?

Comment: `mystring.replace("'", "")` will print the edited string.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace is not an in-place method, meaning it returns a value that you must reassign.

```
mystring = mystring.replace("'", "")
mystring = mystring.replace('"', "")
```

In addition, you can avoid escape sequences by using single and double quotes like so.

Comment: worth mentioning why replace is not in-place - Python strings are immutable.

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable in python. So can't do an in-place replace.

```
f = mystring.replace("'","").replace('"', '')
print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for my situation.

```
#Python 2.7
import string

companyName = string.replace(companyName, "'", "")
```

Answer (score -1):

Using regular expression is the best solution

```
import re
REPLACE_APS = re.compile(r"[\']")

text = " 'm going"
text = REPLACE_APS .sub("", text)
```

input = " 'm going"
output = " m going"